# data centric application: complete UI refresh inefficient

Tags: mysql, sql, database, model-view-controller, database-design

Suppose I have the following three tables and a view for an online
store application with a backend:

```
T_Customers
  cusId
  cusName
  cusPhone

T_Orders
  cusId
  orderId

T_OrderItems
  orderId
  itemName
  itemPrice

V_All
  cusId
  cusName
  orderId
  itemName
  itemPrice
```

In the corresponding views for this data there are 4 corresponding views.
Now suppose I make a modification to one of the first three tables.
The view will become dirty. I will have to refresh it completely
every time the user navigates to it after it has been marked
dirty. This seems very inefficient, keeping in mind that for
the first table once I update a name I can simply fetch the
affected row from a mysql databse and refresh it on the
user interface without having to refresh everything.
Imagine how slow fetching everything in the view
would become once the first three tables contain
1000+ rows each.

How can I tackle this efficiency problem?

Comment: What problem? You have invented one where none exists. Modern databases handle datasets of hundreds of millions of rows and up without blinking. Just write your application, and deal with **real** efficiency problems as they can be provably identified.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused with your use of the word "view". I'm not sure if you mean a view in MVC or a view in the database.

Either way though, I read your question as ... I have a view that aggregates/joins some data and what happens when only one small piece of data changes? Why should I have to pay the price to re-load all the data when only some of it has changed?

I would agree that re-running the view over and over is not efficient. Have you investigated caching?

Between the UI and database layer, I would introduce a cache that stores key/value pairs. Then once a view gets dirty you can either pro-actively expire the item in cache - or just give it a time to live (TTL) and let it expire on its own.

Comment: I like your suggestion of using a cache between the database view and the user interface to speed up things when data needs to be refreshed, but in practice, how would I implement such thing? Do you have some example code or can you point to some references or examples? Thanks.

Comment: Two comments to cover the ideas. =) First some technology options: http://memcached.org/, http://redis.io/, http://www.couchbase.com/.

Comment: Every method in your codebase that makes a database call can be cached. What you need is a unique key that goes into the cache. For example, let's say you have a database call in your code "GetCustomerById(int id)". If you looked up user id 123, your cache key would be "GetCustomerById_123". Another cache key might be "GetCustomerAddress_123". Each key will store the actual object that was returned from the database. Then each time you call the method that looks at the database ... instead of going straight to the database, you check the cache. If you find a key that matches, use that instead.